# Check if array of objects contain certain key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I need to determine if a certain key exists in an array of objects.

Here is a sample array:

```
arrOfObj = [{
        "mainKey1": {
            "subKey1": {
                "innerKey1": {
                    "innerMostKey1": {
                        "key1": "value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey2": {
            "key2": "value"
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey3": {
            "subKey3": {
                "key3": "value"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I was trying to do this but I get the wrong output:

```
const objKeys = Object.keys(arrOfObj)
console.log('objKeys = ' + JSON.stringify(arrOfObj))
```

Output is the index numbers:

```
objKeys = ["0", "1", "2"]
```

I want to have a function that works like this:

```
var isKeyPresent = checkKeyPresenceInArray('mainKey3')
```

Please note though that I only need to check the topmost level in the objects - in above example, these are the main keys (`mainKey1`, etc) and that their content is dynamic (some others have deeply nested object inside and some not so.

Help!

Comment: You need to find key of individual object, not the complete array, loop over the array using some array method and the for each individual element get the keys and test it against your desired key

Comment: Do you want to extract all keys in an array ?

Comment: You get 0,1,2because you passed an array, not an object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using `array.some()`:

```
let checkKeyPresenceInArray = key => arrOfObj.some(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes(key));
```

```js
let arrOfObj = [{
        "mainKey1": {
            "subKey1": {
                "innerKey1": {
                    "innerMostKey1": {
                        "key1": "value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey2": {
            "key2": "value"
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey3": {
            "subKey3": {
                "key3": "value"
            }
        }
    }
]

let checkKeyPresenceInArray = key => arrOfObj.some(obj => Object.keys(obj).includes(key));


var isKeyPresent = checkKeyPresenceInArray('mainKey3')

console.log(isKeyPresent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array, check and see if any of the objects has the key that you are looking for, and return true if it does. If you don't find the key, then the `for` loop will complete and it will return false.

```js
arrOfObj = [{
        "mainKey1": {
            "subKey1": {
                "innerKey1": {
                    "innerMostKey1": {
                        "key1": "value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey2": {
            "key2": "value"
        }
    }, {
        "mainKey3": {
            "subKey3": {
                "key3": "value"
            }
        }
    }
]

function arrayHasKey(arr, key) {
  for (const obj of arr) {
    if (key in obj) { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(arrayHasKey(arrOfObj, "mainKey2"))
console.log(arrayHasKey(arrOfObj, "mainKey10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work,it returns boolean value:

```
arrOfObj.hasOwnProperty('mainKey3');
```

Comment: It returns false even the key exists because it checks properties, not objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` with `hasOwnProperty` like this :

```
let checkKeyPresenceInArray = (key) => arrOfObj.some((o) => o.hasOwnProperty(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **`hasOwnProperty`** method to check if the key is available in the objects in that array -

```
var c = 0;
arrOfObj.forEach(e => {
  if(e.hasOwnProperty("mainKey1")){
       c++;
   }
});
if(c > 0 && c == arrOfObj.length){
    console.log("The key is found in all the objects in the array.");
}
else if(c == 0){
    console.log("The key is not found in any objects in the array");
}
else{
     console.log("The key is  found in some objects in the array");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly to apply `JSON.stringify()` for that purpose:

```
let list = [{
        "data1": {
            "subKey1": {
                "innerKey1": {
                    "innerMostKey1": {
                        "key1": "value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "data2": {
            "key2": "value"
        }
    }, {
        "data3": {
            "subKey3": {
                "key3": "value"
            }
        }
    }
]

let checkIfInArray = key => list.some(obj => JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(key) > -1);


var result = checkIfInArray('key2')

alert(result);
```