# Does array include object with specific key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to find out if an array of a JS object includes an object with a specific key.

I am using,

```
my_array.filter((e) => Object.keys(e).includes(my_key)).length > 0
```

but there must be a way to do it simpler.

Any suggestions in addition to [Check if array of objects contain certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471408/check-if-array-of-objects-contain-certain-key) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.filter(…).length > 0`, use [`.some(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Instead of `Object.keys(…).includes(…)`, use [`… in …`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) (or [`Object.hasOwn(…, …)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) if you need to ignore inherited properties).

So

```
my_array.some(e => my_key in e)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of filter use `some`, already returns true or false and it shortcircuits as soon as it finds the first

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some